# Executing a script within another and ll command is not working

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a very long script and I have to execute in terminal like this:

```
{ . script.sh $1 2>&1 1>&3 | tee err.log; } > output.log 3>&1
```

I also have this line in the beginning of the script:

```
{ exec 0>&9; } 1> /dev/null 2>&1 || exec 9> /dev/tty
```

But, I really want to execute just like:

```
. script.sh $1
```

So, how can I do it?

Until now, I was executing another script like this:

```
. script2.sh $1
```

And the 2nd script is this, just calling a terminal and writing the command to execute the 1st script:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "{ . script.sh $1 2>&1 1>&3 | tee err.log; } > output.log 3>&1; exec bash"
```

But if I do it like this, I have an error. In the 1st script I have to use ll (ls -l) command and it is not working.  It says command not found. If I do it like the 1st option (with the long command) it works perfectly fine.

I though that it was about the argument $1 but it is not because the main script takes it.

Comment: Please remove the tag _ll_, because your post is not related to LL(k)-grammars.

Comment: If it says that the command `ll` is not found, it means that the command does not exist. You did not show how you created `ll`; most likely, it isn't in your PATH.

Comment: I find your script juggling a bit confusing. For instance, what's the reason for doing an `exec bash` after sourcing a script, and if you do it, why are you **sourcing** the script instead of running it? My feeling is that you have a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Comment: **ll** is probably a bash alias.  Those are limited to the current shell, *not exported*.  Unless you source your .bashrc from within the script, you will never have access to all the alias definitions that you have created.  Since sourcing the .bashrc may not actually give your script everything you want them to have available, you might need to create a specific **scripts.ini** which contains all those aliases (and other stuff) you want and *source that from within your scripts*.